# Creating A String with Characters in a While Loop Java

Tags: java, while-loop, filereader, filewriter

I made a scanner program where it reads a fake language and returns a string of numbers to represent keywords, letters/letters with numbers, numbers, and symbols to a text file to be read by a parser.

The issue I'm having is that when on the text file being initially read has a number that has more than one digit it returns like so:

1 = letter

12 = equal

2 = number

777 is the number in the first text.

Ex. In the initial text :   b = 777

the final text: 1 12 2 7 2 7 2 7

When I really want 1 12 2 777

I know I should make the character 777 into a string but my confusion comes from how do I get that to go first when I have in the loop I've posted

I also have another loop for words and again it's the same issue.

Thank you

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

while(text.charAt(i)>='0'&&text.charAt(i)<='9')
            {
                log(Integer.toString(CONST));
                System.out.println(CONST);
                char num =text.charAt(i);
                System.out.println(num);
                log(Character.toString(num));
                i++;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do when your code doesn't work is to shape it into something that's testable, and write a test that fails.

I adapted your code by:

- removing the parts you didn't explain, or that looked irrelevant (`CONST`, and `log()`)
- making write to an arbitrary `Writer`, rather than hard-code `System.out`.

So:

```
 private void consumeDigits(Writer writer, String text) throws IOException {
      int i=0;
      while (text.charAt(i) >= '0' && text.charAt(i) <= '9') {
          char num = text.charAt(i);
          writer.append(num);
          i++;
      }
  }
```

Now I can write a test.

```
@Test
public void printStackTrace() throws IOException {
    String text = "777abcdef";
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    consumeDigits(writer, text);
    assertEquals(writer.toString(), "777");
}
```

The test passes -- so either your code works, or I've misunderstood your requirements. But if you follow this method of working and write a failing test, it's something answerers on SO can help with more easily.

Comment: If you don't know what the `@Test` is, find out about jUnit. It's *very* standard, and it will save your life.